# Remmina doesn't save passwords on 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, lts, remmina

I can switch the password button as long as I want. Remmina won't save passwords or login details and starts up with an empty dialog. What's the issue? I use remmina as it is installed by default.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's unable to write to the config directory (iirc `~/.config/remmina` by default)?

Comment: How to check? On nautilus it says owner can create and delete.

Comment: @steeldriver can you help me or not?

Comment: @steeldriver Stil looking for a valuable answer for this ubuntu-bug.

Comment: Apologies - it's a while since I used remmina. It looks like it uses the default keyring to save passwords - so open your Passwords and Keys applet and check that the default keyring is getting unlocked by your desktop session. As well, there appears to be a `disablepasswordstoring` option setting for the connection itself (which you should find under `.local/share/remmina/` (something like `.local/share/remmina/xxxxxxx_<hostname>.remmina`) so worth checking that as well.

Comment: @steeldriver: What exactly is the passwords ad keys applet? Can I fire it up with the bash?

Comment: The command line version would be `seahorse` I think